# Why does an UPDATE against a table with an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger appear to do a clustered index insert, as well as a clustered index update?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I'll start with a very simple example: two tables, both with the same schema, clustered on PK, but one of which has an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE Standard
(
    PK  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    V   INT NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE InsteadOf
(
    PK  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    V   INT NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT Standard (PK, V) VALUES ('1E58B555-B073-471E-B576-4B09C8E18976', 0)
INSERT InsteadOf (PK, V) VALUES ('1E58B555-B073-471E-B576-4B09C8E18976', 0)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_InsteadOf_Update ON InsteadOf INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @V INT
    DECLARE @cursor CURSOR
    SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT PK, V FROM Inserted
    OPEN @cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @PK, @V
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE InsteadOf SET
            V = @V
        WHERE PK = @PK

        FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @PK, @V
    END
    CLOSE @cursor
    DEALLOCATE @cursor

END
GO
```

If I view the query plan for an update against the standard table, I get the expected clusted index update:

```
UPDATE Standard SET
    V = 1
    WHERE PK = '1E58B555-B073-471E-B576-4B09C8E18976'
```

[image]

However if I perform a similar update against the table with the trigger, I get what appears to be a clustered index insert, as well as the clustered index update:

```
UPDATE InsteadOf SET
    V = 1
    WHERE PK = '1E58B555-B073-471E-B576-4B09C8E18976'
```

[image]

Why is this? I can see the clustered index update I expected later in this query plan (query #4), but why do I get this extra insert at query #1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `INSTEAD OF` trigger stores a copy of the rows that would be affected in a hidden work table*. This is the Clustered Index Insert you see. The trigger body reads from this work table* and any data changes in the trigger use the 'normal' operator (Clustered Index Update in your example).

---

**The query processor internally renames the work table when constructing the user-visible form of the execution plan. When writing to it, it is renamed to the target base table, when reading, it is renamed as `inserted` or `deleted` more or less as people would expect to see in a trigger.*

For more details, see my article [Interesting things about INSTEAD OF triggers](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/09/sql-plan/instead-of-triggers).